# Inserting the same value in the user name field using Stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

How to prevent inserting the same user name in to the Account table using Stored Procedure? 
This is what I have so far

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADD_NEW_ACCOUNT
@accountID DECIMAL (10),
@username VARCHAR (225),
@password VARCHAR (225)
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@accountID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Account (account_id, user_name, password)
     VALUES (@account_id, @username,@password)
    END 
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      UPDATE Account
      SET account_id = @accountID,
        user_name = @username,
        password = @password

    END
END
```

With this code I can insert a user into the Account table, but when I try to insert the same user name I would like to see a message saying this user already exists, and if it does not exist then insert the user name.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Updated the code to include IF statement, with current status the code runs without issue but no values getting inserted

```
(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Writing an existence check is pretty easy -- what have you tried so far?

Comment: Creating a unique index on `user_name` will give you what you want for free.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL server  2012

Comment: The update part makes no sense. Why is the statement updating `account_id` rather than filtering on it?

Answer (score 2):

Got it!! I am sure there are other ways to solve this but, I am happy with this solution :)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADD_NEW_PRODUCT
(
  parameters 
)
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT ....
 BEGIN
    UPDATE Account
    SET .... 
 END
ELSE 
 BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO Account(account_id,....)
  VALUES(@account_id,....)
 END
END;
```